# Union of unique words in two strings

Tags: javascript, regex

Example of string to work with:

Given: "FORD EF FALCON SEDAN" and  "Ford sedan 4dr"
Needed: "FORD EF FALCON SEDAN 4dr"

Using javascript regex, the code below tries to remove the duplicate words "case insensitive" if such word happens to repeat again, thus keeping the first instance of the word and removing the subsequent repeat of the same word.

`let myString = str1+' '+str2;
 myString.replace(/\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b/gi, "$1")`

is giving "FORD sedan 4dr" which is wrong. How can I fix it? thx

Comment: I doubt this is a regexp job.

Comment: Any suggestion how to do it otherwise short of doing a loop to compare each word? Maybe also an observation as to why the down vote? thx

Comment: I agree, sounds like a RegEx is the wrong tool for the job. I'm guessing you have more data than that, perhaps you could expand the question to include some of the other data you want to manipulate. Sounds like you should just be able to create a map and replace based on matching keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using array methods is an easy-to-understand way to solve this problem.

If the result string can just be in all caps then it is pretty easy to do by converting to upper, splitting the string to get an array, and then filtering that array:

```js
let str1 = "FORD EF FALCON SEDAN"
let str2 = "Ford sedan 4dr"

let result = (str1 + ' ' + str2)
  .toUpperCase()
  .split(' ')
  .filter(function(w, i, words) { return i === words.indexOf(w) })
  .join(' ')

console.log(result)
```

If you want to retain the upper- or lowercase-ness of whichever word comes first then I guess you'd do the case-insensitive test while filtering, by using `.findIndex()` instead of `.indexOf()`:

```js
let str1 = "FORD EF FALCON SEDAN"
let str2 = "Ford sedan 4dr"

let result = (str1 + ' ' + str2)
  .split(' ')
  .filter(
    (w,i,words) => i === words.findIndex(v => v.toUpperCase() === w.toUpperCase())
  ).join(' ')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Be aware that this is an O(n^2) method (Mine is O(n)). Works fine though!

Comment: @Triptych - Yep, your way is good and I've upvoted it. In this case I prioritised simple over efficient, but then your way is also pretty simple (and could be simplified further if OK to return the result in all-caps).

Comment: No worries - yours is definitely simpler. Upvoted yours as well.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regex for this. Here's a solution in plain javascript. It's even easier in later versions (where we get a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) type) or using a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4).

```js
// Input
var str1 = "FORD EF FALCON SEDAN";
var str2 = "Ford sedan 4dr";
   
// Make a case-insensitive map.
var key = function(s) {return s.toUpperCase()}
var map = {};

// All words, whitespace-separated, as an array.
var words = [str1, str2].join(' ').split(/\s+/);

// Unique words
var unique = [];

// Find unique words.
words.forEach(function (word) {
  if (!(key(word) in map)) {
    unique.push(word);
  }
  map[key(word)] = 1;
});

// Join back to a string.
var result = unique.join(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Incredibly easy in lodash =)

```js
const strings = [
"FORD EF FALCON SEDAN",
"Ford sedan 4dr",
];

const result = _(strings)
  .map(s => _.split(s, ' '))
  .flatten()
  .uniqBy(_.toUpper)
  .join(' ')
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to split the words and check the array.

You can use regex if you want to but it will remove only 1 duplicate
per replace.

You have to start from the beginning each time.

I.e. `while ( myString.replace(/\b((\w+)\b.*?)\b\2\b/i, "$1")`

I'm not a JS person, so I assume replace() returns a value.

Use this regex `/\b((\w+)\b.*?)\b\2\b/i`

Explained

```
 \b 
 (                             # (1 start)
      ( \w+ )                       # (2)
      \b .* 
 )                             # (1 end)
 \b \2 \b
```